# Align the Button to center Background

Tags: java, android

I need to align the Button of the background.   I need the output like the attached image. Button all should have to be aligned to center of the Blue background not the Logo.

[image: SAMPLE IMAGE]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/feedback_bg" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Frame_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/topbluebar_and" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/alrimal_top_logo" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
        android:text="adfadf" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the attached image?

Comment: show in digram how u want output cause m unable to understand what exactly u want

Comment: You say "I need the output like the attached image" but where is the image?

Answer (score 0):

Hey checkout this if it helps you

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Frame_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo_linear"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="adfadf" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/logo_linear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out..Worked perfectly in my case

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/topbluebar_and" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#035125"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/loginImage"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:src="@drawable/login_header" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/aboutLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/loginLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/aboutImage"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:src="@drawable/about" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aboutbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:text="@string/about"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/syncLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/aboutLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/syncImage"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:src="@drawable/sync" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/synbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:text="@string/sync"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/historyLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/syncLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/historyImage"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:src="@drawable/history" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/historybtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:text="@string/history"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/resourcesLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/historyLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/resourcesImage"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:src="@drawable/resources" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resourcesbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:text="@string/resources"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/alrimal_top_logo" />
```

Comment: Imageview in linear layouts can be set as invisible of you dont want any drawable